# sed insert line on second last line between two brackets

Tags: sed

I have a zone file with the following info:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "master/example.com";
};
zone "example.org" {
    type master;
    file "master/example.org";
};
```

and so on. I need to grep **example.com** and add three lines inside the brackets.

I can get the entire bracket with this:

```
sed -n '/zone \"example.com\" {/,/};/p' zones.local
```

Result:

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "master/example.com";
};
```

I need to add the following three lines so the end result looks like this:

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "master/example.com";
        key-directory "/etc/bind/keys/example.com";
        inline-signing yes;
        auto-dnssec maintain;
};
zone "example.org" {
        type master;
        file "master/example.org";
};
```

But no matter how I try I can't get it to work.
I've tried this for example:

```
sed -n '/zone \"example.com\" {/,/};/p; $i key-directory "/etc/bind/keys/example.com";' zones.local
```

But this will add to the second last line of the entire file, not the second last of the result from the first regex.
Can I make it append the line inside the first regex somehow?

I'm totally stuck and would appreciate som help!

Comment: Using `sed` to parse structured data like an ISC bind configuration file might not be the best idea. Use dedicated parser for this kind of task like [bicop](https://pypi.org/project/bicop/) or [easyzone](https://pypi.org/project/easyzone/)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will definitely look in to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^zone "example.com" {/{:a;h;n;/^};/!ba;x;s#\S.*#key-directory "/etc/bind/keys/example.com";#p;s/\S.*/inline-signing yes;/p;s/\S.*/auto-dnssec maintain;/p;x}' file
```

Focus on lines of the file between `one "example.com" {` and `};`, all other lines will be printed as normal.

When a line beginning `zone "example.com" {` is encountered, make a copy by using the `h` command and then print the current line and replace it with the next using the `n` command.

If the current line does not begins `};`, repeat until it does and then swap to the last line copied, using the `x` command and using the substitute command `s` replace the non-spaced text to the end of the line, with the required new text and print it n.b. the `p` flag on the substitute command. This preserves the indentation and effectively inserts the text before the closing `};`.

Repeat the above for the remaining new text to be inserted and finally swap back to the pattern space and print that too.

Comment: Holy shit, this is the best answer I've ever gotten! Thank you and thank you for your perfect explanation as well.